# laggy laptop caused by orphaned inodes

Tags: mount, hard-drive, firefox, filesystem

So whenever I logout or restart, I've been getting this list of "clearing orphaned inode". I know that it's caused or rather are temporary files that (for reasons beyond my knowledge)can't be cleared until a restart or logout is performed. As a result of this, after a while whenever I'm on my browser (firefox V 55.0.2) my laptop will totally freeze up and I usually have to do a hard shutdown (holding the power button). Now from what I've been told, the possible causes could either be a bad sector or more likely a single sector or area being overwhelmed, I'm thinking from my browser. What makes me think is the latter is because while the problem is getting more frequent, I can get the problem to temporarily go away by minimizing my browser whenever my hard drive works really hard, and then reopening it when my hard drive is back to normal.

So in any case, how can I get this problem to go away for good?

Comment: Do you get read/write errors on your syslog? Install **smartmontools** by typing `sudo apt-get install smartmontools` and check your disk with `smartctl`. `sudo smartctl --all /dev/sdx` will give you a list of your disk data and errors. x=your drive letter. You can also run some tests on your disk using this tool. `smartctl --help` will give you details.

Answer (score 2):

Lets first check your file system for errors.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update:**

Do you dual-boot with Windows? In Windows, have you installed any drivers that allow you to read/write to Ubuntu Ext2/3/4/ partitions? If so, uninstall this driver asap, as it's corrupting your Ubuntu partitions.

Comment: How do you boot "GRUB"? Also, in relation to your second question,  yes I do have dual-boot with windows (win 10 to be precise). What type of drivers could corrupt my ubuntu partition, and how can-I check for them?

Comment: The GRUB menu is what you see when you want to select which OS to boot. The bad Windows driver is something that you would have had to manually install.