# ACPI BIOS error (bug) could not resolve symbol

Tags: boot, 22.04, bios, acpi

Currently I am using `Ubuntu 22.04 64-bit`, GNOME version 42.5 and windowing system Wayland.

My system is Dell G5 5505.

Currently at the time of system boot it shows `acpi bios error (bug) could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCIO.LPCO.ECO], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)` and after few minute the system gets boot. Is this normal or getting error in my system?

If this is the error then could you please help me how to solve this issue.

[image: screen capture of the error is here]

Comment: Most ACPI errors are nothing to worry about. See the answer to this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot So long as your system works normally otherwise don’t worry about it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI error on every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot)

Comment: @PonJar this only answer my question partial. But may be due to this error sometime my system get shutdown on the power fluctuation. Is this due to this error?

Comment: The messages after “recovering journal” are the kind of thing you get after a computer has not shutdown normally. It’s the system fixing any errors in the filesystem that can occur when the system does not shutdown normally. You can get things like that if there is a fault in the hard disk but if this only happens when a power fluctuation has caused a shutdown then it’s nothing to worry about.

Comment: @PonJar this error shown above shows every time system gets boot. And may be due to this error sometime my system get shutdown on the power fluctuation so i want to get rid of this error.

Comment: As a first step follow the answer to this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/960834/laggy-laptop-caused-by-orphaned-inodes